# ffmpeg not taking variables for file name in bash

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have been trying to create a script to download files from a website using ffmpeg, it works well until it gets to the filename, the code is as so:

```
echo "Hello, this is the basic script to download videos. This requires ffmpeg to be installed, do you want to start? (Y/N)"
read start_input
if [ $start_input = Y ] || [ $start_input = y ]
then
    echo "[Text]"
    read video_link
    echo "Now I need what quality you want the video to be (240, 360, 480, 720, 1080, Default: 720)"
    read quality_link
    if [ -z $quality_link ]
    then 
        $quality_link = "720"
    fi 

    echo "Now name the new file (Note, it will have a .ts extention)"

    read $new_file
    echo "And where would you like it to be placed?"
    read $folder_location
    $file="${folder_location}/${new_file}.ts"
    ffmpeg -i "[url]" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts $file
else 
    exit 0
fi
exit 0
```

The problem is when the $file variable is used, ffmpeg doesn't use it, variables are completely ignored, I have tried many different ways but they don't work (Single quotes, double quotes, using ${file}), what can I do?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Give [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) a try -- in this case it says "Don't use $ on the left side of assignments." among several other suggestions.

Comment: You can save a few bits by using `-c copy` instead of `-c:v copy -c:a copy`.

Comment: that other guy, I have tried this but it doesn't work, I have tried just using the raw inputs separated by a slash and it tries to write / so this is not the issue

Answer (score 3):

To assing to a variable in bash, use the following syntax:

```
var=value
var1=$var2
```

No dollar sign on the left hand side, no spaces around the `=` sign.

Comment: That's misleading statement. It would mean that `a=$b` is wrong because `$` is around the `=` sign.

Comment: As said in a comment above, this is not the issue, even after making this change, there is no difference in ffmpeg working

Comment: @2haloes: Remove the dollar sign from `read $variable` also.